# Building a simple app for Windows Mobile 6.5. Where to start?

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-mobile-6.5, windows-mobile-6.1

I'm trying to build a small application for Windows Mobile 6.5 that has a simple menu interface with options. Based on the option the user selects the application goes ahead and overwrites a configuration file stored somewhere in the device. It seems very simple to build for other platforms but I've never actually done any development for Windows Mobile 6.5. I know C++.

I'm looking for pointers on where to look to get started. What are some good resources to learn about windows mobile development that are not too tedious (since my app is so simple)? Are there any other apps/code examples that I can look at to get a head start? Does anyone have any idea how this could be coded?

Thank you!

Comment: May I ask the purpose of this effort?

Comment: Sure. At my workplace they have these scan guns to do inventory, and there are 4 separate configuration files that are used based on what the person is trying to scan. This tool would allow the user to overwrite configuration files and make sure everything is set up before using it.

Comment: So you seems to be supporting an existing application, so why write a new one? Also why not use the code of the existing application as an example to start?

Comment: which existing application? This would be a separate application that sets up the configuration for the other one. I haven't found anything like it.

Answer (score 2):

Before you can start to develop for Windows Mobile in C++ you need a programming environment and the Windows Mobile 6.5 DTK (Device Tool Kit).

For development you normally need a Windows PC and a non-Express version of Visual Studio 2005 or 2008. You may go with the free Microsoft Embedded Visual C++ 4.0 and Windows Mobile SDK (ARM processor). If you do not have access to VS2005 or VS2008 (even VS2003 will work), it will be expensive or hard to get as MS now sells VS2015, but only VS2003/2005/2008 are designed to compile Windows Mobile 6.x code.

There is also a free GNU Windows CE toolkit usable for Windows Mobile programming. Depends on your skills.

A good starting point is to know about general Windows Programming (Charles Petzold's Programming Windows book is a good base).

The Windows Mobile SDKs/DTK come with samples for C++ SmartDevice programming too. These are good starting points.

There are other options, for example Mono Develop with workarounds to get Compact Framework compatible IL code. But this is .NET programming and not C++.